# Google calendar meet link not being created automatically via Google Calendar API (PHP)

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Google calendar meet link not being created automatically via Google Calendar PHP API.
Google Calendar API stopped creating a hangout meeting link automatically. The same code was working a few months back but not not not.

**Code**

```
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => $summary, //'Google Calendar summary',
  'location' => $location, //'USA',
  'description' => $description, //'Book Room',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => $sessionStartTime,//'2018-08-16T14:30:00-00:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => $sessionEndTime,//'2018-08-16T14:30:00-01:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => $attendeesEmailNEW,'resource' => true),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));
    
$calendarId = 'primary';        
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
$createdID = $event->getId();
```

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: Code has been updated to understand the issue in better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

In order to create the conference data property in an Event you will have to send a request with the ConferenceDataVersion flag activated.

> **conferenceDataVersion** : Version number of conference data supported by the API client. Version 0 assumes no conference data support and ignores conference data in the event's body. Version 1 enables support for copying of ConferenceData as well as for creating new conferences using the createRequest field of conferenceData. The default is 0. Acceptable values are 0 to 1, inclusive.

To pass this setting in PHP you can use the following instruction:

```
 $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1]);
```

When setting this flag you will also have to create an Event property called `conferenceData.createRequest`

> The conference-related information, such as details of a Google Meet conference. To create new conference details use the `createRequest` field. To persist your changes, remember to set the `conferenceDataVersion` request parameter to `1` for all event modification requests.

Example:

```
"conferenceData" => [
        "createRequest" => [
          "conferenceSolutionKey" => [
            "type" => "hangoutsMeet"
          ],
          "requestId" => "123"
        ]
      ]
```

### Reference

[Create Events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events)

[Calendar API Event insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)